# Text center ul pagination in div wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, pagination

I've been trying to center the content which contains ul pagination. The margin-left and margin0right only center the div, but text-align: center won't center the content inside.

Here's the code:

CSS

```
/* Pagenation */
.article .pagelinks { text-align: center !important; display: table; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 240px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; clear: both; }
.article .pagelinks ul { list-style:none; text-align: center; margin: auto; padding: 0; }
.article .page-numbers li {display:inline;}
.article .page-numbers li a {display:block; float:left; padding:4px 9px; margin-right:7px; color: #911d23;}
.article .page-numbers li span.current {display:block; float:left; padding:4px 9px; margin-right:7px; background-color: #fff; color: #911d23;}
```

And here's the link to the web page in question: http://disa.com.sv/constructora/?page_id=10&paged=2.

How do I get it to text-align center or center things?

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in the question itself. If the problem gets fixed in the link (or it goes dead) this question will be of no use to other users experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
.article .page-numbers li{display:inline-block}
```